# Automap in sqlalchemy is not passing mapped classes that I can query

Tags: python, excel, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to pull data from an excel file into sqlalchemy for querying. I am able to pull the data, but I can not query it. I try to setup [Automap](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html) from the docs, but the maps never get made and my last line of code does not work.

Script I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd
path='./app/static/upload/'
name='Sample_Employee_data_xls.xls'
df=pd.read_excel(path+name)
df.to_sql(name,con=db.engine)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=[name])
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()
#This code can not work because 'name' does not exist as a mapping.
Name = Base.classes.name
```

The error I get says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bob/microblog/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 188, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: name
```

#This shows my table exists in the database so I am unsure what else needs to be done.

```
db.engine.table_names()
```

Comment: What do you get if you print `Base.classes.items()`?

Comment: Not sure why, but it comes back as an empty list.

Comment: That suggests that the table does not exist, or perhaps there's a problem with the name.  What RDBMS are you connecting to?